# File Upload doesn't create UploadedFile

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-2.4

I am currently working on a PHP v5.5.9 project in which I am using some standalone components (I **do not** use the full-stack framework), currently the following:

```
psr/log                      1.0.0   Common interface for logging libraries
sonata-project/intl-bundle   2.2.1   Symfony SonataIntlBundle
symfony/debug                v2.4.2  Symfony Debug Component
symfony/dependency-injection v2.4.2  Symfony DependencyInjection Component
symfony/event-dispatcher     v2.4.2  Symfony EventDispatcher Component
symfony/form                 v2.4.2  Symfony Form Component
symfony/http-foundation      v2.4.2  Symfony HttpFoundation Component
symfony/http-kernel          v2.4.2  Symfony HttpKernel Component
symfony/icu                  v1.2.0  Contains an excerpt of the ICU data and classes to load it.
symfony/intl                 v2.4.2  A PHP replacement layer for the C intl extension that includes additional data from the ICU library.
symfony/locale               v2.4.2  Symfony Locale Component
symfony/options-resolver     v2.4.2  Symfony OptionsResolver Component
symfony/property-access      v2.4.2  Symfony PropertyAccess Component
symfony/security-core        v2.4.2  Symfony Security Component - Core Library
symfony/security-csrf        v2.4.2  Symfony Security Component - CSRF Library
symfony/templating           v2.4.2  Symfony Templating Component
symfony/translation          v2.4.2  Symfony Translation Component
symfony/twig-bridge          v2.4.2  Symfony Twig Bridge
symfony/validator            v2.4.2  Symfony Validator Component
twig/extensions              v1.0.1  Common additional features for Twig that do not directly belong in core
twig/twig                    v1.15.1 Twig, the flexible, fast, and secure template language for PHP
```

I have one *Entity* class, one *FormType* class and one *Controller* and I am able to persist the *Entity* via a "Twig" template *View*. So the full stack is working correctly.

Then I added a [`File`](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.html) attribute to my *Entity*, in order to add an image file as described in the official documentation][1](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html). I've also extended my *FormType* with the following code:

```
$builder->add('pictureFile', 'file', array('label' => 'Image File'));
```

After running the updated code (with an image file selected), the following error is shown:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to MyEntity::setPictureFile() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File, array given, called in [.]\vendor\symfony\property-access\Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor.php on line [.] and defined in MyEntity.php on line [.]
```

So, Symfony **does not** automatically create a [`UploadedFile`](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html) from the form, but binds the `$_FILE` data to an `array`. I've noticed, that other people do also have this problem:

- [how to make symfony2 Request object to pass UploadedFile object to entity class instead of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960954/how-to-make-symfony2-request-object-to-pass-uploadedfile-object-to-entity-class)
- [Symfony2 multiple file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667366/symfony2-multiple-file-upload)

At the moment I am using the following code in my *Controller*, but I would like to use the auto-binding feature (because at the moment I cannot validate the uploaded file in the *Entity*).

```
$formType = new MyType;
$entity = new MyEntity;
$form = $this->formFactory->create($formType, $entity);
$form->handleRequest();

if (true === $form->isSubmitted()) {
    if (true === $form->isValid()) {
        // TODO Replace ugly workaround to partially solve the problem of the file upload.
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $file = $request->files->get('myentity')['pictureFile'];

        // Persist entity, upload file to server and redirect.
    }
}

// Load View template.
```

**Edit (2014-03-03):** Here's the relevant code of the *Entity*:

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;

class MyEntity
{
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $picture;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getPictureFile()
    {
        return $this->pictureFile;
    }

    public function setPictureFile(File $pictureFile = null)
    {
        $this->pictureFile = $pictureFile;
    }

    public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
    {
        $metadata->addPropertyConstraint(
            'name',
            new Assert\NotBlank
        );
        $metadata->addPropertyConstraint(
            'name',
            new Assert\Type('string'));
        $metadata->addPropertyConstraint(
            'pictureFile',
            new Assert\Image(
                array(
                    'maxSize' => '2048k',
                    'minWidth' => 640,
                    'maxWidth' => 4096,
                    'minHeight' => 480,
                    'maxHeight' => 4096
                )
            )
      );
    }
}
```

And the source code of the *FormType*:

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class MyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text')
            ->add(
                'pictureFile',
                'file',
                array('label' => 'Image File')
            )
            ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Save'));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'myentity';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => __NAMESPACE__ . '\MyEntity'));
    }
}
```

Any suggestions how-to get this work?

**Edit (2014-03-07):** Simplified source code in preparation for my answer.

Comment: Does your form have the correct enctype attribute?

Comment: Yes, the form is generated as follows: <form name="myentity" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: I did: See above please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution for the problem described in the question. Since this seems to be a problem many people have, I describe my solution in this answer.

During my research I've come across a [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/issues/27), which contains a dummy *DataTransformer*.

After reading the content of that page, I came up with the idea to try it with a custom *DataTransformer* which converts the `array` into an instance of `UploadedFile`.

Here is the step-by-step solution:

1. Create a [*DataTransformer*](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) named `UploadedFileTransformer` with the following source code:

   ```
   use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
   use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;


   class UploadedFileTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
   {
       /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        *
        * @param array $data The array to transform to an uploaded file.
        *
        * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile|null The
        *         uploaded file or `null` if no file has been uploaded.
        */
       public function reverseTransform($data)
       {
           if (!$data) {
               return null;
           }

           $path = $data['tmp_name'];
           $pathinfo = pathinfo($path);
           $basename = $pathinfo['basename'];

           try {
               $uploadedFile = new UploadedFile(
                   $path,
                   $basename,
                   $data['type'],
                   $data['size'],
                   $data['error']
               );
           } catch (FileNotFoundException $ex) {
               throw new TransformationFailedException($ex->getMessage());
           }

           return $uploadedFile;
       }

       /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        *
        * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile|null $file The
        *        uploaded file to transform to an `array`.
        *
        * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile|null The
        *         argument `$file`.
        */
       public function transform($file)
       {
           return $file;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Update the *FormType* to use the `UploadedFileTransformer` for a `file` type input field (compare with the code in the question):

   ```
   use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
   use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
   use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

   class MyType extends AbstractType
   {
       public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
       {
           $builder->add('name', 'text')
               ->add(
                   $builder->create(
                       'pictureFile',
                       'file',
                       array('label' => 'Image File')
                   )->addModelTransformer(new \UploadedFileTransformer)
               )
               ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Save'));
       }

       public function getName()
       {
           return 'myentity';
       }

       public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
       {
           $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => __NAMESPACE__ . '\MyEntity'));
       }
   }
   ```
3. Remove crap from the *Controller*, in my example the access to the `Request` object to obtain the uploaded file (compare with the code in the question).

   ```
   $formType = new MyType;
   $entity = new MyEntity;
   $form = $this->formFactory->create($formType, $entity);
   $form->handleRequest();

   if (true === $form->isSubmitted()) {
       if (true === $form->isValid()) {
           $file = $entity->getPictureFile();

           // Persist entity, upload file to server and redirect.
       }
   }

   // Load View template.
   ```

And that's it. No fiddling with attributes in the *FormType* and the validation in the *Entity* is also working.

I really don't know, why this isn't the default behavior of the Symfony components? Maybe I missed to register something in my startup code?

Answer (score 0):

just add the multipart to the form and it should work

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

</form>
```